# how to split tuples within a RDD

Tags: pyspark

```
myRDD.collect()
```

gives below output:

```
[('best', {'times'}),
 ('age', {'foolishness', 'times', 'wisdom'}),
 ('wisdom', {'age'}),
 ('times', {'age', 'best', 'worst'}),
 ('worst', {'times'}),
 ('foolishness', {'age'})]
```

When I attempt to split contents here in spark using:

```
myRDD.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
```

I get an error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

My expected outcome is below:

```
 [(‘times’, [(‘best’)]),
 (‘times’, [(‘worst’)]),
 (‘age’, [(‘foolishness’)]),
 (‘foolishness’, [(‘age’)]),
 (‘wisdom’, [(‘age’)]),
 (‘times’, [(‘age’)]),
 (‘age’, [(‘wisdom’)]),
 (‘age’, [(‘times’)]),
 (‘best’, [(‘times’)]),
 (‘worst’, [(‘times’)])]
```

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Comment: @Psidom my expected outcome is updated above. Appreciate hints or suggestions.

Comment: Try `myRDD.flatMap(lambda t: [(v, t[0]) for v in t[1]])`